# Masonry layout with Next.js

Tags: next.js, masonry, server-side-rendering

I am developing a multi-page website using Next.js for the frontend and Strapi for the backend. On the blog page, the data is dynamically fetched from the database. I am trying to display this data in an adaptive layout using Masonry.

The problem I am having is that on first load, the page displays every grid-item in a single vertical column. On reload, the Masonry layout then takes effect, but with some overlapping items. On a second reload, everything then displays properly and is even responsive. However, if I navigate away from the page and come back, it is back to square one.

Here is the code for the blog page :

```
import React from 'react';
import Layout from '../components/StaticLayout';
import Link from 'next/link';
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch';
import '../../static/styles.min.css';

let Masonry = '';

export default class Blog extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      appIsMounted: false
    }
  }

  static async getInitialProps() {
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:1337/blogposts');
    const data = await res.json();

    return {
      posts: data
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    let masonry = await import('masonry-layout');
    this.setState({
      appIsMounted: true
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Layout>
        <h1 className="blogHeader">Blog</h1>
        {this.state.appIsMounted ? (
          <div className="grid js-masonry" data-masonry-options='{ "itemSelector": ".grid-item", "columnWidth": 400 }'>
            {this.props.posts.map(
              post => (
                <div key={post.id} className="grid-item">
                  <Link href="/p/[id]" as={`/p/${post.id}`}>
                    <img src={`http://localhost:1337${post.Image.url}`} alt={post.Image.name} className="postImage" />
                  </Link>
                  <div className="text">
                    <Link href="/p/[id]" as={`/p/${post.id}`}>
                      <a className="postLink">{post.Title}</a>
                    </Link>
                    <p className="blurb">{post.Content.substring(0, 300) + '...'}</p>
                    <Link href="/p/[id]" as={`/p/${post.id}`}>
                      <button className="viewPost">Read More!</button>
                    </Link>
                  </div>
                </div>
              )
            )}
          </div>
        ) : null}
      </Layout>
    )
  }
}
```

To be noted, the *StaticLayout* script only ensure the header is at the top of each page.

**EDIT**

So I've solved the overlapping part of the problem. Instead of initializing Masonry in the html, I've added a js file to './static'. On my blog page, I've added the following :

```
import Head from 'next/head'

...

return(
  <Head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/runMasonry.js"></script>
  </Head>
  ...
)
```

And the runMasonry.js file looks like this :

```
window.onload = function () {
  var elem = document.querySelector('.grid');
  var msnry = new Masonry(elem, {
    // options
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    columnWidth: 160,
    gutter: 20
  });
}
```

But when I first arrive on the page or navigate away and come back, the elements are still displayed in a column and require a reload.

Comment: Sounds like css loading issue, do u have the same issue on production build?

Comment: @felixmosh Yes, it is the same problem after running next build and next start

Comment: Do you use next-css?
Do you see any network errors related to css?

Comment: @felixmosh Yes, I am using next-css to load a minified css file into the blog page. And my page has no network errors. All responses are 200 with a couple of 302

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Came up with a non-ideal fix, but it works.

Added the following code to the *runMasonry.js* file :

```
window.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", function () {
    var elem = document.querySelector('.grid');
    if (elem) {
        var msnry = new Masonry(elem, {
            // options
            itemSelector: '.grid-item',
            columnWidth: 160,
            gutter: 20
        });
    }
});
```

So it detects when new page content is loaded and, if it finds my *.grid* element, re-runs masonry.

Leaving this open in case someone can provide a better, long-term solution.